# Django retrieve filter value in views.py

Tags: python, django

I would like to prompt the user a dropdown box with all the values of a specific attribute, and retrieve this value in views.py to use it as function argument (to filter the output of a view function).

Example:

`models.py`

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

`views.py`

```py
def users(request):
    users= User.objects.all()
    context = {'users': users}
    return render(request, 'users.html', context)
```

`users.html`

```html
{% block content %}

<div>
    <table style="width:100%" class="table table-hover table-sm table-stripped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>E mail</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for i in users%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.email}}</td>
                <td>{{i.address}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

</div>

{% endblock content%}
```

I would like to display in my html a dropdown with all the User.name values, and when selected use the selected_user value as an argument in views.users() to filter the displayed table.

Any idea on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you could make a form like this

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="users">Choose a user:</label>
    <select name="users" id="users">
        {% for user in users %}
            <option value="{{ user.name }}">{{ user.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

and then when submitted, get the value of selected option using like this

```
selected_user = request.POST.get('users')
```

or something along these lines

Answer (score 0):

In your `html` add `select` element and append `users` data first with `<table>` body empty.

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control" id="user" name="user">
        {% for i in users %}
            <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <table id="userTable" style="width:100%" class="table table-hover table-sm table-stripped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>E mail</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And in your `script` call new `url` using [**jQuery.ajax()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) with every [**.change()**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event of `<select>` element to get corresponsing user value with provided `userid` value and append data to the table. By this way you don't need to `refresh` the page and get your data with every `change` event.

```
<script>
    $('#user').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/user/" + $(this).val(),
            method: 'GET',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                var tr = '<tr><td>'+ data.name +'</td><td>'+ data.email +'</td><td>'+ data.address +'</td></tr>';
                $('#userTable tbody').append(tr);
            },
            error : function(x) {
                console.log(x);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in your `urls.py` add new url as

```
path('user/<str:user_id>/', views.user_data, name='user-data')
```

Add in your `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse

def user_data(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(GuruUsers, id=user_id)
    user_data = {
        'name' : user.name,
        'email' : user.email,
        'address' : user.address
    }
    return JsonResponse(user_data, status=200)
```

Comment: how to access this path through a navbar ?

Comment: `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'user' %}"> filter HTML </a>` gives me a No reverseMatch, but how can I provide context for user_id when it does not exist yet

Comment: also, when directly accessing the url, I am only seeing the json objects, that is because in views.py user_data does not provide render towards user.html, is that normal ?

Comment: Add new `url` for fetching provided user id. I have added new url only for rendering single user data and for users use your previous url. You will have two `urls`. If you have not id then fetch data through `username` by sending username from html. For id `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'user' user.id %}">` and in case of `username` then `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'user' user.username %}">`. And yes return `json` data and append to table after `ajax` success you don't have to render for this case